# Chrome Render Bug that Occurs in Facebook

Tags: google-chrome

Well last days i bumped into an issue with Rendering the Facebook through Chrome 46,

Till now it have been occured only on Facebook page, on different areas.

Beside the black areas, some times the navigation bar disapears and only the "Search Facebook" persists. But when i'm scrolling the page these areas are getting lost.

It seems that in 2013 there was a Similar Bug found on this Link:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=142038

But it sais that this issue has been resolved...
[image: Uhm What]
Update: Just Happened to Stackoverflow Aswell:
[image]

This is Chrome's GPU Report:
[image]

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue also occurs on my Chrome 46. I also looked that post ([crbug.com/142038](http://crbug.com/142038)).

And I got an answer from that post, one told me to check if toggling the flag `chrome://flags/#disable-slimming-paint` makes different.

So I **turn on** the flag, and those black blocks is gone. Therefore I think you may try this workaround.

And I have posted a new issue on crbug.com, which is related to this problem. ([crbug.com/547356](http://crbug.com/547356))

And you may post a reply to confirm the issue if you have freetime.

Comment: It seems that it hasn't appeared any issue till now. Thanks